# TestFlight iOS 8 - Error: An invalid app was specified for the install request

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios8, xcode6, testflight

I'm trying to use the new TestFlight on iOS 8 but I'm getting the following error: "An invalid app was specified for the install request" when the user (myself) taps on the Install button in the TestFlight app.

I went through the configuration of the app in iTunesConnect, set up internal testers (including myself) and sent invitations. I then opened the invitation on my iPhone with iOS 8 GM ; the TestFligh app opened showing the invitation and the install button. This is where I see the error message when I tap Install.

Has anyone been facing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Was able to get the build to successfully install simply by entering something in the "Test Information" in iTunes Connect.  For example, I entered text for "What To Test" and hit save, got a notification the build was ready, and it successfully installed.

Comment: coming across the same issue, adding text for "What To Test" didn't resolve it for me

Comment: After adding this text it worked for me eventually. It still seems al little unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

This error also seems to come up when the iTunesConnect servers are not working properly. It seems like the TestFlight beta distribution system is a bit overloaded now. It took 30 minutes to "process" the build for distribution. We filled in the what to test field, but this error still popped up. Most recently, it took about 30 minutes from the notification that there was a new build to test until it was able to successfully install. I tried to look at the info in iTunesConnect, but it errored out when selecting the app from MyApps screen.